# Ao printar um campo com o php do banco de dados ele não identifica as váriaveis

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar um gerador de textos automáticos mas alguns textos vão ter variáveis neles ( exemplo nas imagens ). existe a possibilidade de ele identificar? estou usando o campo longtext no banco para os campos que devem ser printados
[image: resultado no navegador]

[image: texto no banco de dados]

Edit: os campos em questão estão sendo identificados e printados em outro lugar pois já fiz o teste o problema ocorre apenas quando as variáveis vem do banco de dados

````
                 $SelectCabecalhotxt = $PDO->prepare($SelectCabecalhotxt);
                 $SelectCabecalhotxt->execute();
                 if ($SelectCabecalhotxt->rowCount()>0){
                     while($row2 = $SelectCabecalhotxt->fetch()){
                         echo"<div>
                         <input type='radio' id='operacaotxt".$row2["id_copi_texto"]."' name='operacaotxt' value='".$row2["copi_texto"]."'>
                         <label for='operacaotxt".$row2["id_copi_texto"]."'>".$row2["copi_texto"]."</label>
                     </div>";
                     }
                 };```
````

Comment: Como não consegui que ele identificasse elas quando vinham do banco usei a grafia *quartos* , assim loco após o select eu passo uma lista substituindo todas as palavras com ** por suas respectivas variáveis *quartos* por $quartos, *vagas* por $vagas e assim por diante. Provavelmente não é o ideal mas deu certo

Answer (score -2):

Tente definir suas variáveis fora do html é mais confortável para se programar.
Já com as variáveis definidas o seu código precisa ser php nas variaveis então ficaria

```
                 $SelectCabecalhotxt = $PDO->prepare($SelectCabecalhotxt);
                 $SelectCabecalhotxt->execute();
                 if ($SelectCabecalhotxt->rowCount()>0){
                     while($row2 = $SelectCabecalhotxt->fetch()){
                         echo"<div>
                         <input type='radio' id='operacaotxt<?php echo $row2["id_copi_texto"]?>' name='operacaotxt' value='<?php echo $row2["copi_texto"]?>'>
                         <label for='operacaotxt<?php echo $row2["id_copi_texto"]?>'><?php echo $row2["copi_texto"]?></label>
                     </div>";
                     }
                 };
```

de qualquer forma sempre tente definir suas variáveis fora da area do front. (serio ajuda muito) :)